# Testing Material UI Component with Jest and Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui

I am trying to test a React component that uses `<ExpansionPanel />` as its sub-component with Jest and Enzyme.

For reference, console.log(wrapper.debug()) looks like below:

```
const wrapper = shallow(<SomeComponent/>);
console.log(wrapper.debug());

<Fragment>
  <WithStyles(ForwardRef(ExpansionPanel)) defaultExpanded={true}>
    <WithStyles(ForwardRef(ExpansionPanelSummary)) expandIcon={{...}} aria-controls="panel1a-content" id="panel1a-header">
      <p className="summary text">
        Basic Options
      </p>
    </WithStyles(ForwardRef(ExpansionPanelSummary))>
    <WithStyles(ForwardRef(ExpansionPanelDetails))>
      <Connect(OptionDetails) optionType="basicOptions" />
    </WithStyles(ForwardRef(ExpansionPanelDetails))>
  </WithStyles(ForwardRef(ExpansionPanel))>
  <WithStyles(ForwardRef(ExpansionPanel)) defaultExpanded={false}>
    <WithStyles(ForwardRef(ExpansionPanelSummary)) expandIcon={{...}} aria-controls="panel1a-content" id="panel1a-header">
      <p className="summary text">
        Advanced Options
      </p>
    </WithStyles(ForwardRef(ExpansionPanelSummary))>
    <WithStyles(ForwardRef(ExpansionPanelDetails))>
      <Connect(OptionDetails) optionType="advancedOptions" />
    </WithStyles(ForwardRef(ExpansionPanelDetails))>
  </WithStyles(ForwardRef(ExpansionPanel))>
</Fragment>
```

As you can see, it renders Material UI's components as Higher Order Components (wrapped inside `WithStyles`). I was just wondering if it is okay to just do something like below to test whether the component is rendering properly.

```
// Notice how I am explicitly specifying WithStyles(ForwardRef())
expect(wrapper.find('WithStyles(ForwardRef(ExpansionPanel)')).toHaveLength(x);
```

I found a really similar problem, but there are no answers posted as of now.
[Similar post (no answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58459291/testing-material-ui-with-jest-outputs-shallowwrapper-in-my-snapshot)

Thanks ahead.

**EDIT**
For clarification, what I suggested above works, but I was just wondering if this is the correct way of testing HOCs.

Also, using enzyme's `dive()` does not really work because the actual component I am testing is not HOC (it thinks there are no sub-components to dive into).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if what you suggested would work. Something like this would probably work better.

```
const expansionPanelElements = wrapper.find(Fragment).filter(item =>item.exists('ExpansionPanel')));
expect(expansionPanelElements.toHaveLength(x));
```

Comment: I just edited my question. But yeah, what what I initially suggested actually works, but I was just wondering if there are more elaborate ways of testing such case.

Comment: Ah ok. Great. I didn't realize you could do it the way you had specified also. Very useful.